# HDMI not working on ubuntu 18.10, no screen detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hdmi, 18.10

I have newly installed ubuntu on my computer that has both an Intel graphics card and an nvidia card. The nouveau drivers which is the default simply freezes the system after about 15 seconds, even from a live usb stick. But after blacklisting nouveau I could install ubuntu. (Then I redid that for my new install too.) This made the HDMI port stop working, but that was fine. Then I tried to install Nvidians proprietary  drivers, which surprisingly enough worked, even the HDMI port, except for quite a lot of screen tearing.

I followed this(https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-fix-video-tearing-in-videos-nvidia-ubuntu) tutorial on how to get rid of the screen tearing, but all the settings were already right.

After that I tried both `nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"` and `nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"` but they didn't work, they only made the screen laggy.

After rebooting it to get rid of what those commands did the HDMI port simply stopped working, the only trace of it working I can find is that on Wayland it's detected, but doesn't actually output anything.

The card in question is a quadro p600, which I think is directly connected to the HDMI port so I can't use the intel card as a backup.

(If I didn't provide enough information feel free to ask, I'm not an expert on the subject.)

Comment: Both cards use the same ports in hybrid graphics systems (laptops; not applicable to most desktops).

Comment: Maybe, but because the wrong drivers mess up that port it seems like it at least has a lot of control over the port

Comment: It's true that you probably need the Nvidia drivers to use the HDMI port with the Nvidia graphics as well as to actually switch between Intel and Nvida graphics. But if it happens to be running with the integrated Intel Graphics then 1) the correct drivers are already installed and in use and 2) the HDMI port should work and doesn't depend at all on the Nvidia graphics. The Quadro P600 requires **410 drivers version**. Please try purging whatever drivers you already installed and then install the aforementioned version at Additional Drivers.

Comment: If you notice any problem please post a question about it specifically. **A guide from 10 years ago like the one you linked is unlikely valid for the current Ubuntu and may make things worse.**

Comment: Will try when I get to my computer

Comment: I tried to purge the drivers and install them again, but it did not work. The problem did not get fixed. It says the 410 drivers are installed. 

Because my system is so newly installed I think I'm just gonna reinstall ubuntu, it wont fix the screen tearing but it's much better than not having an external screen at all